# Python, How to render Text Emoji with Pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame, render, emoji

How do I render a emoji in a string in python 3.6 using pygame(font.render(), font.freetype/font.font)? If not possible anymore, I need a code for render in Pillow Draw.text(). I would be grateful.
Discard this: (Filling this question of nothing because looks like my post is mostly code, so I'm adding some nothings to enable the post)

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import pygame, emoji
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("segoe-ui-symbol.ttf", size=50)
#font = pygame.font.SysFont("segoe-ui-symbol.ttf", 72)
font_color = (255,255,255, 255)
font_background = (0,0,0, 0)

text_string = emoji.emojize('')
#text_string = u'ujiHelloÁpQ|, World '
#text_string = u'ujiHelloÁpQ|\U0001f44d, World '
#print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up_sign:'))
#text = font.render("♛", True, font_color, (0,0))
#text = font.render(text_string, True, font_color, (0,0))
text = font.render(text_string, fgcolor=font_color, size=0)

image_size = list(text[0].get_size())
text_image = pygame.Surface(image_size)
text_image.fill(font_background)
pygame.display.flip()

text_image.blit(text[0], (0,0))

#print(dir(text_image))

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #screen.blit(text,
    screen.blit(text_image,
        (320 - text[0].get_width() // 2, 240 - text[0].get_height() // 2))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible problems here.

First, if nothing is showing up or the app seems to stall, then Pygame cannot find the `SysFont`. This was happening on Mac, because there is no `segoe-ui-symbol.ttf` as system font. As such, I downloaded a [version from the internet](https://www.wfonts.com/font/segoe-ui-symbol) and created a normal `freetype.Font` from it.

It works fine.

The second problem may be that the font itself doesn't have those characters in it. Sometimes the OS replaces characters that a font cannot render with a different font.